# How do I get a record from the most recent archive table that an ID occurs in

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, greatest-n-per-group

I have linked databases from MAS (accounting system) in SQL Server 2008 R2. The way payroll records work in this database is that each quarter, an archive of the payroll tables are made, and a new current quarter table is made with any terminated employees removed. It does have unique employee IDs. The structure is identical in the archive and current versions.

So, in the 2nd quarter of the year, an employee who was terminated in the 1st quarter, is only in the 1st quarter copy of the database. An employee who worked in both the 1st and 2nd quarters is in the 1st quarter copy and the 2nd quarter copy. An employee who was hired in the 2nd quarter only occurs in the 2nd quarter.

I need to be able to build a set (temp table, view, whatever) to work with that includes the most recent record for each employee. This set will be the basis for queries like turnover, average wage by position, etc.

I can build a list of IDs quickly enough with a `UNION` of the `EmployeeID` column, but other columns change over time (pay rate, address, etc), so I cannot simply `UNION` all of the columns, as I will have duplicates for some employees.

Is there a reasonably efficient way to merge the historical databases together, keeping only the most recent row for each employee? Having phrased the question that way, should I just make a series of `MERGE`s, stepping back through the archive copies from newest to oldest, inserting when not matched? Is there a better way?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you can approach this problem.  Here is one:

- Create a view to merge the tables, adding an appropriate archive date column to each
- Create a sub query against the view to Group on EmployeeID and get the MAX archive date
- Use the sub query to join with the view and get the latest record for each employee

Create a sample table schema and test data

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF OBJECT_ID('Employee', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE Employee;
    GO
    IF OBJECT_ID('Employee2012Q1', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE Employee2012Q1;
    GO
    IF OBJECT_ID('Employee2012Q2', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE Employee2012Q2;
    GO

    CREATE TABLE dbo.Employee (
        EmployeeID      int IDENTITY(1,1)   NOT NULL    PRIMARY KEY
       ,EmployeeName    varchar(50)         NOT NULL
       ,StartDate       smalldatetime       NOT NULL
       ,EndDate         smalldatetime       NULL
       ,Salary          decimal(18,2)       NOT NULL
       ,Position        varchar(50)         NOT NULL
       ,HomeAddress     varchar(200)        NOT NULL
    )

    -- Employees hired
    INSERT dbo.Employee SELECT 'John Doe', '01/01/2012', NULL, 50000, 'Developer', '12345 Main St, New York, NY'
    INSERT dbo.Employee SELECT 'Jane Doe', '01/01/2012', NULL, 52000, 'Developer', '837 1st St, New York, NY'

    -- Employee fired
    UPDATE A
       SET A.EndDate = '02/01/2012'
      FROM dbo.Employee A
     WHERE A.EmployeeName = 'John Doe'

    -- Table archived
    SELECT * INTO dbo.Employee2012Q1 FROM dbo.Employee

    --  Remove fired employees
    DELETE dbo.Employee WHERE EndDate IS NOT NULL

    -- Employee hired
    INSERT dbo.Employee SELECT 'Jack Flash', '04/01/2012', NULL, 73000, 'Manager', '9580 21st St, New York, NY'

    -- Employee fired
    UPDATE A
       SET A.EndDate = '05/01/2012'
      FROM dbo.Employee A
     WHERE A.EmployeeName = 'Jack Flash'

    -- Table archived
    SELECT * INTO dbo.Employee2012Q2 FROM dbo.Employee

    --  Remove fired employees
    DELETE dbo.Employee WHERE EndDate IS NOT NULL

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
    GO
```

Create a view that merges all the employee tables

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('EmployeeArchive', 'V') IS NOT NULL DROP VIEW dbo.EmployeeArchive
    GO
    CREATE VIEW dbo.EmployeeArchive
    AS
    SELECT CONVERT(smalldatetime, CONVERT(char(10), GETDATE(), 101)) as [ArchiveDate]
          ,EmployeeID
          ,EmployeeName
          ,StartDate
          ,EndDate
          ,Salary
          ,Position
          ,HomeAddress
     FROM dbo.Employee 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONVERT(smalldatetime, '03/31/2012') as [ArchiveDate]
          ,EmployeeID
          ,EmployeeName
          ,StartDate
          ,EndDate
          ,Salary
          ,Position
          ,HomeAddress
      FROM dbo.Employee2012Q1 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONVERT(smalldatetime, '06/30/2012') as [ArchiveDate]
          ,EmployeeID
          ,EmployeeName
          ,StartDate
          ,EndDate
          ,Salary
          ,Position
          ,HomeAddress
      FROM dbo.Employee2012Q2 
    GO
```

Get the latest info for each employee

```
    SELECT A.*
      FROM dbo.EmployeeArchive A
      JOIN (
            SELECT EmployeeID, MAX(ArchiveDate) as MaxArchiveDate
              FROM dbo.EmployeeArchive
             GROUP BY EmployeeID
           ) B
        ON A.EmployeeID  = B.EmployeeID
       AND A.ArchiveDate = B.MaxArchiveDate
```